# Python: Tracing the Execution of a For Loop

Tags: python, if-statement, trace, conditional-statements

I am attempting to trace the execution of a piece of code that contains a `for loop` with two `if conditionals`. But I need help understanding exactly how `for loops` are executed in python.

Please consider the following example:

```
  numAs = 0
  numEs = 0
  aStr1 = 'abcdefge'
   def someFunc(aString):
1.     for i in range(len(aString)): 
2.           if s[i] == 'a': 
3.               numAs += 1 
4.               continue 
5.           if s[i] == 'e': 
6.               numEs += 1 
7.               if numEs > numAs:  
8.                    break 
9. print(someFunc(aStr1))
```

Question: Using `aStr` as a parameter how many times will line 1 execute in the above code?

My understanding is that line 1. of this piece of code: `for i in range(len(aString))`, will only be executed once. While lines 2 and 5 will be executed multiple times depending on the string that is passed. When the function encounters the `continue` statement it goes back to line 2 and runs it. Please confirm or correct my thinking.

Thanks

Comment: What definition of the `continue` statement have you read?  Can you provide a link or a reference to the tutorial you're using?  It's not clear what you've read, so it's not clear what you're *really* asking.

Comment: the book i am reading is 'Python Programming in Context' by Brad Miller. This question is not from the book i'm just trying to understand exactly how iteration works. I've made a few edits to my question. hopefully it is now more clear.

Comment: Not related to the topic at hand, but you could just do `for c in aString`. Right now you are creating a list of n integers (n being the length of the string, retrieving integers from that list one at a time, and using them to index into a string, when you could just iterate directly over the characters of the string.

Comment: "exactly how iteration works"?  What do you mean by "exactly"?  It seems like you're asking several things about looping, some of which are trivial and some of which obvious.  Can you be more clear on what's confusing you.

Comment: question has already been answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of what the code does is correct.

FWIW, it is easy to follow the execution of a script using `python -m trace --trace some_script.py` or you can see the execution line counts with `python -m trace --count some_script.py`.

For example, the latter call to *trace* produces:

```
    1: def someFunc(aString):
            global numAs, numEs
    1:      s = aString
   10:      for i in range(len(aString)): 
    9:            if s[i] == 'a': 
    2:                numAs += 1 
    2:                continue 
    7:            if s[i] == 'e': 
    1:                numEs += 1 
    1:                if numEs > numAs:  
                           break

    1: numAs = 0
    1: numEs = 0
    1: someFunc('flammable')
```

Comment: okay so this is saying that the line `for i in range(len(aString)):` was ran ten times?

Comment: Yes, it ran ten times (including the final iteration that determined that there was no more work to do).