# Tracing the execution of a Python program line/statement by line programmatically

Tags: python, pdb

What would be the easiest way to execute a Python script and, for each executed statement, pass the line number or the line itself to a callback function?  For example

A piece of code to be executed

```
for i in range(5):
    z = i**2
```

and a callback

```
def callback(line):
   print line
```

The output would be:

```
for i in range(5):
    z = i**2
for i in range(5):
    z = i**2
for i in range(5):
    z = i**2
...
etc
```

Another way of stating this is that I want to know the piece of code that would be next to execute if I were running the script stepping through a debugger.. I've seen [this question about tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032484/python-tracing-the-execution-of-a-for-loop)  but I'm interested in doing more than tracing the number of times executed in the callback function.

A debugger is going to be helpful,  but only if I can run it non-interactive mode with the ability to call back to the python code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [sys.settrace](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function. This allows you to specify a tracing function which is executed for every line of code. It was, I think, specifically implemented to create `pdb` so it's at the right level of abstraction you seem to want. Implementing what you want will not be trivial but I think it's the best place to start.

For an production program that uses this, look at [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).

Answer (score 2):

Accepting Noufal's answer since it put me on the right path, but this helped as well

http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html

Answer (score 2):

The April's fools module `goto` is a working example of tracing implemented in Python, so although it's doubtlessly slower (than the C implementation in coverage.py), it's rather easy to understand. http://entrian.com/goto/

Comment: Thats... sort of horrible, but interesting :)

Comment: @dfb Indeed. It also shows how to change the execution head to another line. Based upon that code, I implemented an absolute and relative JMP instruction. Quite fun.