# How to programmatically execute/step through Python code line by line

Tags: python, interpreter, pdb

I am trying to find a way that I can have a program step through Python code line by line and do something with the results of each line.  In effect a debugger that could be controlled programmatically rather than manually.  pdb would be exactly what I am looking for if it returned its output after each step as a string and I could then call pdb again to pickup where I left off.  However, instead it outputs to stdout and I have to manually input "step" via the keyboard.

Things I have tried:

1. I am able to redirect pdb's stdout.  I could redirect it to a second
   Python program which would then process it.  However, I cannot
   figure out how to have the second Python program tell pdb to
   step.
2. Related to the previous one, if I could get pdb to step all the way
   through to the end (perhaps I could figure out something to spoof a
   keyboard repeatedly entering "step"?) and redirect the output to a
   file, I could then write another program that acted like it was
   stepping through the program when it was actually just reading the
   file line by line.
3. I could use exec to manually run lines of Python code.  However,
   since I would be looking at one line at a time, I would need to
   manually detect and handle things like conditionals, loops, and
   function calls which quickly gets very complicated.
4. I read some posts that say that pdb is implemented using
   sys.settrace.  If nothing else works I should be able to recreate
   the behavior I need using this.

Is there any established/straight forward way to implement the behavior that I am looking for?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Tracing the execution of a Python program line/statement by line programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789744/tracing-the-execution-of-a-python-program-line-statement-by-line-programmaticall?rq=1)

Comment: Below you say you got it working.  Did you spoof stdin to step through, or did you find a way to call something like pdb.do_step()?  Can you give some details of your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.settrace()` is the fundamental building block for stepping through Python code.  pdb is implemented entirely in Python, so you can just look at the module to see how it does things.  It also has various public functions/methods for stepping under program control, read the library reference for your version of Python for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I was looking at [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) but the commands it describes use the debugger prompt rather than a program.

I got the pdb source at [link](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pdb.py) and I've been trying to access the methods directly.  Calling run opens the debugger prompt:
myPdb = pdb.Pdb()
myPdb.run(test)

However, I have not found a method that steps through without a prompt.
myPdb.do_step("test = "a = 10\nb=20\nprint a + b")
which doesn't work.

Do you have any advise on where I should go from here?

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long to accept your answer; things got crazy with the holidays.

I was able to get it to work with pdb!

Answer (score 1):

> I read some posts that say that pdb is implemented using sys.settrace.
>   If nothing else works I should be able to recreate the behavior I need
>   using this.

Don't view this as a last resort. I think it's the best approach for what you want to accomplish.